# How to manipulate the labels of a factor by applying a function

Tags: r

Given a data frame with a factor

```
library(dplyr)

my_data <- data.frame(my_f = LETTERS[1:5],
                      stringsAsFactors = TRUE)

my_data |>
 str()
```

I want to adapt the factor's labels

```
my_data <- my_data |>
 mutate(my_f = as.factor(paste('Constant part', my_f)))

my_data |>
 str()
```

How can this be done more beautiful, i.e. maybe without converting into a string and back to a factor?

Comment: See `forcats::fct_relabel`. `fct_relabel(as.factor(LETTERS[1:5]), ~paste('Constant part', .))`

Comment: write your own function and use that. 
`afp <- function(f,p){
  as.factor(paste(p, f))
}


my_data <- my_data |>
  mutate(my_f =afp(my_f,'Constant part')) `